# Pass $_FILES into class for processing

Tags: php, file-upload

I currently have an enquiry submission form that can only be completed by registered users.

Part of the form allows the user to upload a file to be attached to their enquiry.

What I am attempting to do is pass the `$_FILES` variable to a class file for processing (using [class.upload.php](http://www.verot.net/php_class_upload.htm)) as I want the file name to be in the following format:

enquiryID_userID_fileName.ext

Is it possible to pass the form `$_POST` data to a class along with the `$_FILES` data?

An example of what I am attempting to achieve is the following:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit_enquiry'])) {
    $enquiry = new Enquiry();
    $enquiry->newEnquiry($_POST, $_FILES);
}
```

Then in the Enquiry Class:

```
class Enquiry {

    private function _processFiles($_FILES, $caseID) {
        ...
    }

    private function _processForm($_POST) {
        ...
    }

    public function newEnquiry($_POST, $_FILES) {
        $caseID = $this->_processForm($_POST); // returns caseID
        $this->_processFiles($_FILES, $caseID);
    }
}
```

A print of `$_FILES` gives me the following:

```
Array
(
    [file] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Blue hills.jpg
                    [1] => Sunset.jpg
                    [2] => 
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => image/jpeg
                    [1] => image/jpeg
                    [2] => 
                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => /tmp/phpwyLp86
                    [1] => /tmp/phpKJa4iw
                    [2] => 
                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 4
                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 28521
                    [1] => 71189
                    [2] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

When attempting to process the file it's almost as if the tmp file has been lost as it can't process the file to be uploaded. Are there any obvious issues I have missed attempting to implement this solution?

Comment: Variables are always variables. What exact problem have you found?

Comment: Have updated the question with more information :)

Comment: can you check if the files still exist in tmp folder?

Comment: Avoid naming your method arguments the same as any super globals. Try changing it to `public function newEnquiry(array $postData, array $fileData)` or something like that (for all three of your methods)

Comment: @Phil - I had overlooked that but it's likely to be the answer. You should post it as such.

Comment: @Phil - Thank you for that, something I had overlooked there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The upload tmp files will be deleted when your script finishes. As long as it didn't finish, the files are still there.

However, if you move them or if the form goes accross multiple requests (e.g. multi-step form, validation that requires re-submission), you need to build your own tmp files.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to prepend the post values to the file name:

```
foreach($_FILES as $file){
   $file['name']=$_POST['enquiryID'].'_'.$_POST['userID'].'_'.$file['name'];
}

// do upload
```

And if you only have a few $_POST inputs, save them as sanitized variables and send them individually through your function as parameters (as Phil said).